# Teradata : Using Column reference with the Interval Parameter

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a problem with a query, I want to subtract an interval to a date. The interval parameter is a value of a column.

```
HINIC               | IREFT | IPERDC

2022-06-28 00:22:15 | DAY   | 3

2022-07-10 20:00:39 | MONTH | 1
```

The result I wanted would be

```
HINIC               | IREFT | IPERDC | RESULT

2022-06-28 00:22:15 | DAY   | 3 | 2022-06-25 00:22:15

2022-07-10 20:00:39 | MONTH | 1 | 2022-06-10 20:00:39
```

I tried to used "interval" but it looks like it doesn't accept columns as parameters.

When I use "interval" with a column, like this

```
Select 

CAST(HINIC AS DATE) - INTERVAL IPERDC DAY 

from table
```

It returns this error

> SQL Error [3707] [42000]: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.06] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a string or a Unicode character literal between the 'INTERVAL' keyword and the word IPERDC

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression such as `(IPERDC * INTERVAL '1' MONTH)` or `CAST(IPERC AS INTERVAL MONTH(4))` would be syntactically valid, but not recommended. Using `ADDMONTHS()`  for month and year calculations safely handles the fact that not all months have the same number of days.

You can safely use DAY intervals in that way, but Teradata allows `DATE` +/- `INTEGER` number of days directly.

```
CASE IREFT
  WHEN 'DAY' THEN CAST(HINIC AS DATE) - IPERDC
  WHEN 'MONTH' THEN ADDMONTHS(CAST(HINIC AS DATE),-1*IPERDC)
  WHEN 'YEAR' THEN ADDMONTHS(CAST(HINIC AS DATE),-12*IPERDC)
END
```